# Tokenize by using regular expressions (parenthesis)

Tags: regex, string, split, tokenize

I have the following text:

`I don't like to eat Cici's food (it is true)`

I need to tokenize it to

`['i', 'don't', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'Cici's', 'food', '(', 'it', 'is', 'true', ')']`

I have found out that the following regex expression `(['()\w]+|\.)` splits like this:

`['i', 'don't', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'Cici's', 'food', '(it', 'is', 'true)']`

How do I take the parenthesis out of the token and make it to an own token?

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Do you plan to split or match these tokens? It might be easier to match them with [`\w+(?:'\w+)?|[^\w\s]`](https://regex101.com/r/kYcsPD/1).

Comment: what is the difference between split and match? To sum up the problem what i need is (foo) -> ["(", "foo", ")"])

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: The language is english

Comment: I mean what programming language are you using the pattern in?

Comment: Programming language:python

Comment: Great, then use `re.findall(r"\w+(?:'\w+)?|[^\w\s]", s)`

Comment: There are some quotation marks missing. Why findall?I Need to split the sentence in tokens

Comment: Sorry, the double quoted string literal must be used, I edited the comment. It does *tokenize* the string. Just test and you will see. `w+(?:'\w+)?` will match all 1+ word char chunks followed with an optional `'` followed with 1+ word char substrings, and `[^\w\s]` will match a single char other than word and whitespace characters.

Comment: well, works fine thx. So could you tell me which expression i need only for (foo) -> ["(", "foo", ")"]? I'm trying to understand what you have done

Comment: Only for `(foo)` - `re.findall(r'\w+|\W', s)` - match 1 or more word chars (`\w+`), or (`|`) 1 non-word char (`\W`). But if you plan to avoid matching whitespaces (that can be matched with `\W`) you need to exclude them from the pattern using `[^\w\s]`. It is a kind of  a contrast principle with exceptions. I will post an answer.

Comment: I added two solutions in my answer, if there is anything unclear, please let me know.

Comment: yes, how does re.findall(r'\w+|\W', s) look like with avoiding whitespaces is not clear

Comment: `\W` matches whitespace. To subtract the `\s` from `\W`, you need to convert `\W` to the negated character class `[^\w]` (matching any char but a word char) and add `\s` to it - `[^\w\s]` that matches any char but a word *and* whitespace chars.

Comment: (foo) with [^\w\s] => ['(', ')']

Comment: No idea why  you used just that, see https://ideone.com/RZTxmI. Read my answer below.

Comment: What do you mean? It matches `(`, `foo` and `)`. [Look here](https://ideone.com/fS2QIq).

Comment: Thx, works fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to tokenize a string with regex with special restrictions on context, you may use a matching approach that usually yields cleaner output (especially when it comes to empty elements in the resulting list).

Any word character is matched with `\w` and any non-word char is matched with `\W`. If you wanted to tokenize the string into word and non-word chars, you could use `\w+|\W+` regex. However, in your case, you want to match word character chunks that are optionally followed with `'` that is followed with 1+ word characters, and any other single characters that are not whitespace.

Use

```
re.findall(r"\w+(?:'\w+)?|[^\w\s]", s)
```

Here, `\w+(?:'\w+)?` matches the words like `people` or `people's`, and `[^\w\s]` matches a single character other than word and whitespace character.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VNECfC/1)

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/xh6buG):

```
import re
rx = r"\w+(?:'\w+)?|[^\w\s]"
s = "I don't like to eat Cici's food (it is true)"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

Another example that will tokenize using `(` and `)`:

```
[^()\s]+|[()]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VNECfC/2)

Here, `[^()\s]+` matches 1 or more symbols other than `(`, `)` and whitespace, and `[()]` matches either `(` or `)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate singular char tokens (the brackets in this particular case) from the chars which represent a token in series:

```
([().]|['\w]+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/RQfYhL/2